# How to add row with bit values to mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have tried everything, but I get a crazy space or a 0001 bitmap when I do a select all on that table.

I have tried

```
insert into web_admin_roles values("SuperAdmin",b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'0',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1');
insert into web_admin_roles values("SuperAdmin",0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1,0b1);
insert into web_admin_roles values("SuperAdmin",'true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true','true');
insert into web_admin_roles values("SuperAdmin",b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'1',b'0',1,1,1);
insert into web_admin_roles values("SuperAdmin","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1");
```

Table Described

```
mysql> describe web_admin_roles;
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| roleIdentity         | varchar(64) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| addNewAdmin          | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| viewAdmin            | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modifyAdmin          | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| removeAdmin          | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| approveUser          | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| viewUser             | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modifyUser           | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| removeUser           | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| addFacility          | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| viewFacility         | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modifyFacility       | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| removeFacility       | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| addManager           | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| viewManager          | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| modifyManager        | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| removeManager        | bit(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| isSuperAdmin         | bit(1)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| createdTimeMilliSecs | bigint(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updatedTimeMilliSecs | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| isRecordActive       | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: If you are using MySQL, why not use a set of `enum` values?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by _crazy space or a 0001 bitmap _ & what you expect to get back.

Comment: Sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/78e66/1) : in MySQL workbench I actually get 1's & 0's back rather than true/false.

Comment: select addNewAdmin+0 from web_admin_roles;